# Overflow-X appearing on body instead of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have to make a horizontal list type component, and this is how I am planning the css with the parent container in the pink color and list-items in black

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .box{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: rgb(77, 61, 92);
            height: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .inner{
            margin: 10px;
            height:100%;
            min-width: 400px;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The issue is, the scrollbar appears on the body, which is not the parent of the list-items. The "box" component is, but the scrollbar doesnt appear on that. Ultimately I will rid the scrollbar by overflow:none , but the items are considering their scroll parent as "body" instead of my "div" that I created.

What am I missing here ?

Thank you for your time

Comment: `overflow: scroll` on `.box`

Comment: Or `overflow: auto` on `.box`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .box{
            background-color: rgb(77, 61, 92);
            height: 300px;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            align-items: center;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
        .inner{
            margin: 10px;
            height:100%;
            min-width: 400px;
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
        <div class="inner"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works. Thank you. I should also mention that as commented by @Heretic Monkey above, overflow-x:scroll also works.

Comment: @LakshayDutta You are welcome. Hit me with thumbs up :)

Answer (score 0):

I did not see the overflow-x property on the `.box` class on the code you provided